# Custom сборка vlc

Tags: mediaplayer, vlc

Посоветуйте, можно ли собрать установщик с custom версией vlc плеера(с зашитым плейлистом iptv). Что бы имея .ехе установщик, получить уже рабочую программу с настройками и плей-листом. Может вопрос и глупый, но поиск в google мне ничего не дал. Помогите ссылками или направлением поиска инфы.
Спасибо!

Comment: с технической точки зрения конечно возможно. Начните с изучения сорцов - https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-sources.html - и скомпилируйте себе правильный бинарь. Потом разберитесь, какой инсталлятор там используется и научитесь собирать инсталляционный пакет. А дальше добавить туда один файл будет делом техники.

Comment: Спасибо,буду разбираться.